# Selecting drop down option using CasperJS

Tags: javascript, html-select, casperjs

I've got stuck when I tried to select an option with CasperJS, tried many casperJS functions, but none of them did the trick so far, maybe there is a simple way to make a selection to this kind of form?

```
<form class="_messageBoxForm" id="messageBoxForm" name="messageBoxForm" method="post" action="" data-source="">
    <select class="_time _hours">        
         <option value="1">1</option>          
         <option value="2">2</option>       
         <option value="3">3</option>       
         <option value="4">4</option>         
         <option value="5">5</option>          
         <option value="6" selected="selected">6</option>                       
    </select>
</form>
```

Things I have already tried:

```
this.evaluate(function() { 
$('._time._hours').val('5').change(); 
}); 

this.evaluate(function() { document.querySelector('select._time._hours').selectedIndex = 2; 
return true; 
}); 

this.fillSelectors('form#messageBoxForm', { 
'select[class="_time _hours"]': '5' 
}, true);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the below solution it might help you

```
casper.then(function(){
    this.click("._time._hours");
    this.evaluate(function() {
        var form = document.querySelector('.form-control');
        form.selectedIndex = 2;
        $(form).change();
    });
});
```

Comment: If the above solution has worked for you, then please up vote it

Comment: Had to change one line in your code for it to work:
$(form).val(2).change();
Thank you ;)

Comment: I used '   casper.click("#commencement-date");
   this.evaluate(function(){
    var form = document.querySelector('#commencement-date');
    form.selectedIndex = 2;
    $(form).change();
   });' and worked perfectly, so thank you +1

Answer (score -2):

Prateek, your solution worked for me, but I had an Id to work with.

```
this.evaluate(function(){
    var form = document.querySelector('#searchSelectId');
    form.selectedIndex = 3;
    $(form).change();
});
```